# Find input type with PHP

Tags: php, html, post, input

I'm asking for your help because I would like to automate something in my form processing in PHP.

My goal is to know the HTML type of a `$_POST` variable.
For example, if it is a `<input type="number" name="tata">`, in my PHP processing, I would like to transform the content as `(int) $_POST['tata']` and make some verification.

The final goal is to be able to use one verification for all my fields and all my forms on my website to convert the variables as the good format I'm waiting before sending data to my database.

Is there any way to do this in PHP ?
I know that I can get the type with jQuery but I would like to avoid this method.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: `gettype` might be of interest to get you started

Comment: if `type="number"` only integer will allowed, you can also use `is_numeric($_POST['tata'])` to check if the value is a number or not

Comment: All values sent to the server will be parsed as strings, no matter the value. PHP won't know if the value `"1337"` came from a `type="number"` or `type="text"`-field. What you can do is to add hidden fields with the input types for each normal input field

Comment: gettype will not help me
is_numeric will not help me too because I would like to automate all my verifications with a foreach on all my POST fields

@MagnusEriksson, you're right, It can be a way to do my stuff thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

All values sent to the server will be parsed as strings, no matter the value. PHP won't know if the value "1337" came from an input with `type="number"` or `type="text"`-field. Those types are simply for the UI on the client.

What you can do is to add hidden fields with the input types for each normal input field.

Example:

```
<input type="number" name="num[value]" value="1337" />
<input type="hidden" name="num[type]" value="number" />
```

If you do that for each input, then you can validate each value on the server:

```
// Access a value directly
$type  = $_POST['num']['type'];
$value = $_POST['num']['value'];

// Or iterate through the items and do something
foreach ($_POST as $key => $param) {
    $type  = $param['type'];
    $value = $param['value'];

    // Do your thing...
}
```

#### Note

This is *not* a secure way of automating validation on the server. Since the data comes from the client, none of it can really be trusted. If someone wants to send in invalid data, they could simply change the type in the form before posting.